# EF Core: How to add the relationship to shadow property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two classes:

```
public class DbLibrary
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<DbDepartment> Departments { get; set; } = new List<DbDepartment>();
}

public class DbDepartment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In this *model* I need `DbDepartment` hasn't the property contained the link to `DbLibrary`. But I need the cascade delete on the database side. For this purpose I add the shadow property to `DbDepartment`. It is the foreign key. How to relate the primary key `DbLibrary` class with the shadow property?

This is my attempt:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // Create the shadow property
    var id = builder.Entity<DbDepartment>().Property<Guid>("LibraryId");

    // Create the relationship for cascade delete
    builder.Entity<DbLibrary>().HasMany(n => n.Departments)
        .WithOne(m => id /* it is wrong */).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a shadow property. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties . I.e. the "LibraryId" column is only in the table of database but `DbDepartment` class hasn't property with this info.

Comment: According to the cited link you need to add `public DbLibrary Library { get; set; }` to `DbDepartment`. Does this work?

Comment: I need this property to be absent in the model. I pointed this out in the topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shadow properties represent a primitive properties (FK in your case) and cannot be used to create navigation property.

In order to configure the relationship end without navigation property, you use the corresponding `Has` / `With` parameterless overload. Whether the FK is shadow or regular property doesn't matter. It matters when you configure the associated FK using `HasForeignKey` method, which means that for shadow properties you have to use the overload with `string` property name rather than lambda expression.

Here is the desired fluent configuration:

```
builder.Entity<DbLibrary>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Departments)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("LibraryId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, how could we do if we had another table using 'LibraryId' as foreign key? Let's say that we also have DbLibrary2 that contains a list of departments. Can both of them share the LibraryId mapping?